# How to use LAN1 port as second WAN port? (dir-615)

Tags: port, dd-wrt, vlan, iptv

I have STB, internet connection with PPPoE and router D-link DIR-615 with dd-wrt. I want to STB ip will be assign from ISP directly. Or set up iptv something different.

P.S. Router is D-link DIR-615 rev. **E4**

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what problem you're trying to solve. What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not quite understand how to configure vlan for iptv (STB) on the dd-wrt. Forums described this problem with the dlink-320 (also on the dd-wrt). The problem was solved by creating a second wan port for STB with the command `switch`, but I have this command is not available. I tried various options with the `nvram`, but nothing has been achieved.

Comment: What problem? We still have no idea what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The problem is that iptv does not work on TV. Usually a wire from the provider, the wire from the STB and the wire from the wi-fi router connected to an unmanaged switch, which broadcasts multicast packets to all ports. I wanted to do it with only one router.

Comment: are you running the latest version of dd-wrt? if so, what version is it?

Comment: yes, i tried last version (03.19.2012) of dd-wrt from brainslayer

Answer (score 2):

From the DD-WRT web page, go to `Setup` and then `VLANs`. Choose the port the LAN 1 port (1) and put it in the same VLAN the WAN (W) port is in. (Probably by unchecking VLAN 1 and checking VLAN 2.)

Comment: I don't have tab `VLANs`. In the `Setup` -> `Networking` there are VLAN tagging, bridging, port setup, etc., but they are all bound to the interfaces (eth0, eth1, ath1, etc) I tried to do it through an SSH client commands `nvram set vlan0ports = ...` `vlan1ports`, but have not figured out where each port. The maximum I could do is give the WAN port in the off state.